# ReactJS: How to use refs() for setting 'innerHTML' inside component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here I am trying to set `innerHTML` from my `Test.js` on render inside my `componentDidMount`. On the process I am getting errors of `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null` .

I have gone through few questions where it defined to use `refs()` but unfotunately not able to use this in my case.

Any suggestion how can I use `refs()` here in my example?

`demo Test.js`

```
function updateList() {
    const json = JSON.parse(localStorage["values"]);
    if (json) {
        picture = json.picture;
        if (picture) {
        userPicture = picture.name;
        }

    }
    console.log(userPicture, "userPicture");
    document.getElementById('picture').innerHTML = userPicture;
}

async function getAll () {
    await updateList();

}

export default {
    getAll
};
```

`TestComponent.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import Test from './Test';

class TestComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        Test.getAll();
    }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="test-item" >
            <div className="test-picture" id="picture"> </div>
        </div>

    );

  }
};


export default (injectIntl(TestComponent));
```

Comment: does `document.getElementById('picture')` matched anything ?

Comment: yes.. <div className="test-picture" id="picture"> </div> . This is an example although. But same format is being there.

Comment: @aeXuser264 any help here ?

Comment: well,  i cant catch any problem from the above example, can u provide minimum reproduced example in a sandbox ?

Comment: Are you just experimenting? Because what you are trying to do is antipattern, you shouldn't set `innerHTML` directly. If you absolutely have to set html, use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Comment: @Riwen thanks for your time. actually this was before written inside palin html with script. So it was working . Now I am turning this into reactjs where I am unable to set the innerhtml and innertext.

Comment: I have tried this as well. But no luck till now. what I am missing not bale to figure out.

Comment: @Riwen do you mind to provide an answer of possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want.

Code sandbox url - https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-surf-n72h6?file=/src/index.js

App.component

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Test from "./Test";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.divRef= React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() { 
    Test.getAll(this.divRef);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="test-item">
        <div className="test-picture" ref={this.divRef} id="picture">
          Hello from component
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const container = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(container);
render(<App />, container);
```

Test.js

```
function updateList(ref) {
  ref.current.innerHTML = "Hello from Test.js";
}

async function getAll(ref) {
  await updateList(ref);
}

export default {
  getAll
};
```

Comment: Hi Praneeth, Thanks for your time. Yes it is working for a single ref if I have 3 refs with like for picture, music , art etc.. Any luck there

Comment: I am actually against using too much refs :-). Refs is very much like a pointer to one control. So you should be creating that many instances of references. As you mentioned 3 then 3 React.createRef() instance and attach to the control which you want to use.

I hope I did not misunderstand your question. A code sandbox /snippet might help me understand better

Comment: any other solution then.. As This seems not so workable here for 3 different or may be more.

Comment: As because getAll() will return music , art, picture etc which How cn I handle then.And I have some other innertext as well .

Comment: As well as some error is also coming here . Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'current' of undefined

Comment: Why not build a react picture component instead of using the Test.js file? You can pass the props to the component and that should handle whatever logic needed. Are you getting the unhandled error in the code sanbox which I shared?

Comment: yes getting unhandled error. as I mentioned that there are many innerhtml texts which needs to be display. Need to figure this out .

Comment: Accepting this as answer because this process can be folowed for a single refs. Thanks